# How to clear or close notification from notification bar click on close button in android

Tags: android, notifications

[image]

I use below code how to achieve my motto, I want to close or clear notification from notification bar click on close button

```
Intent moreNewsIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AppService.this, 0, moreNewsIntent, 0);

                        // expanded view of the notification.
                       /* Intent close = new Intent(this, AppService.class);
                        close.setAction(CommonConstants.ACTION_DISMISS);
                        PendingIntent piDismiss = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, close, 0);*/


                        int notificationId = new Random().nextInt(); // just use a counter in some util class...
                        PendingIntent dismissIntent = NotificationActivity.getDismissIntent(notificationId, AppService.this);


                        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                                .setTicker("News Notification")
                                .setContentText(getString(R.string.lbl_notification_title_news))
                                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND| Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                                .setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 100)                            
                                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title))
                                .setContentIntent(pIntent)


                                .addAction (R.drawable.news_negative,getString(R.string.btn_more_nes), pIntent)
                                .addAction (R.drawable.close,getString(R.string.btn_close), dismissIntent)

                                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

NotificationActivity.java

```
public class NotificationActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_ID = "001";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(getIntent().getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, -1));
        finish(); // since finish() is called in onCreate(), onDestroy() will be
                    // called immediately
    }

    public static PendingIntent getDismissIntent(int notificationId,
            Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
        PendingIntent dismissIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        return dismissIntent;
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".NotificationActivity" android:taskAffinity="" android:excludeFromRecents="true">
```

Thanx in advance help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You want to add functionality to close the notification on top of the already defined functionality of swipe to dismiss? Typically a close button is only added for something like a foreground service.

Answer (score -1):

Call [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)) with the same id you initialized the notification with.

If you are asking how to get a PendingIntent to do a cancel() call, it looks like you were on the right track with [PendingIntent.getService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)). A better approach would probably be to use [PendingIntent.getBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)), register a receiver in the manifest, and do the call from there.

Comment: This belongs to comments section!

Comment: Why? This is an appropriate answer for this question.